# angularjs fields blocked

Tags: html, angularjs

I have an issue with my Angular application, but it's only in my PC; on another one, it's working.

I have some fields that are blocked (not disabled); when I try to edit an item, it's frozen.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="form-group left-text " >
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12" >Question :</div>
    <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-12">
        <input type="text"  class="form-control" ng-model='item.question'  value="<%item.question%>"  ng-disabled='currentDict.id != 0'><br/>
    </div>
</div>

$scope.onLoad = $http({
    method: 'get',
    url: '/item'
}).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.item = data;
```

What could freeze this field and other fields too?

in the same form i have these two lists one in the bottom is working and the other is frozen ! the half of the form in the top is frozen :

```
<div class="form-group left-text " >
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12" >Question language :</div>
            <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-12">
                <select class="form-control"  id='qlang'
                    ng-model='newQlang'
                    ng-options='language.language for language in qlanguages track by language.id'
                     >
                </select><br/>
            </div>
        </div>
  <div class="form-group left-text" >
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12">Answer language :      </div>
                    <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-12">
                        <select class="form-control"  id='alang'
                            ng-model='newAlang'
                            ng-options='language.language for language in alanguages track by language.id' >
                        </select><br/>
                    </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: did you inspect you application?

Comment: yes tere is no error in the console ! there is lists that are not responding too

Comment: then check your frozen  html element. i think then you will find your problem. if everything is ok then i think it maybe a browser related issue. then you can try in different browser or updated version.

Comment: Did you clear your browser cache?

Comment: yes i did ! the problem is that is working in another pc and not in mine